# Back word compatible with new added member

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper, automapper-5

I am adding a new data member in a class which is part of shared nuget package. On Server application, I need to support both nuget packages, previous nuget package member does not have newly added member. How do I map this member so my code does not break. Please review following code.

Nuget Package 1.0

```
Class Employee
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Address { get; set;}
}
```

Nuget Package 1.1

```
Class Employee
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Address { get; set;}
   public string Department { get; set;}
}
```

From the client, if Department member is not passed I want to set server Department to Null else set the value passed by client.

Comment: Does client pass the value of `Department` right now?

Comment: Create  Employee Partial class and add Department prop in that class

Comment: Client is currently using Nuget Package 1.0, so department is not used in current code, but they will consume this property in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure I fully understand the issue I believe what your looking for may be auto-property initializers:

```
class Employee
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Address { get; set;}
 public string Department { get; set;} = null;
}
```

Look here for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx